# PHP form submitting to the wrong email address

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, submission

I have a select field within a form (below) that allows the user to select a specific 'agent' in which they want the form to be emailed to. The code below displays the correct name and email for the agents.

```
<select name="to" class="select-box">
    <option value="">Send message to</option>
        <?php if(isset($agents) && $agents):
            if(!is_array($agents)) { $agents = array($agents); }
                foreach($agents as $agent):
                    $agent_post = get_post($agent);
                    $email = sanitize_email(get_post_meta( $agent, '_meta_email', true ));
                    $mailto[] = $email;
                    echo '<option value="'.$email.'">'.wp_kses_data($agent_post->post_title).'</option>';
            endforeach;
        endif;
    ?>
</select>
```

... now is when things start to get tricky. The PHP to actually use the selected email is not working properly.

```
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
if(!$to) $to = nt_get_option('property', 'contact_email', get_bloginfo('admin_email'));
```

The second line acts as a backup plan if no email address is selected, however it's being used even if the user has selected a specific agent. Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Is your email script sending to any email address value that is submitted using the form? If so, this would be easily abused by spammers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `!$to` is what you are looking for. `!$to` actually means `!= true` which obviously an email address does not equal true, therefore it will always use the default email address.

I would try

```
$to = trim($_REQUEST['to']); // trim whitespace

// Check if $to is empty
if(empty($to)){
    // If so, set default
    $to = nt_get_option('property', 'contact_email', get_bloginfo('admin_email'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @VIDesignz, but that didn't seam to solve the issue

Comment: @ColoursB Hmmm...there must be an issue somewhere else in the processing page.